# uncaught ReferenceError: start is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

i'm making a calendar with fullcalendar.io, i'm new to javascript and i'm getting the error that is listed in the title of this page and i dont really understand what is causing it. what i'm trying to do is when you click on a date it opens up the bootstrap modal where you can write notes. in the modal title i want to show the start date for the note, but it says undefind in the html page, and in the console.log it says the error lies at `var tgl=moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')` here is the chunk of code where the error lies:

```
<script>

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {          
      selectable: true,
      selectHelper: true,
      select: function(start, end, alldays){
      $("#BookingModal").modal('toggle');
      }
  
    });
    
    calendar.render();
  });

  var tgl=moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')

type="text/javascript"
src="{{ url_for('static', filename='index.js') }}"


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because the variable `start` on the line:

```
  var tgl=moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

is not declared in the scope of that code. If you want to use the `start` variable that's in your `select` function, you should move that line inside that function:

```
      select: function(start, end, alldays){
      $("#BookingModal").modal('toggle');
     var tgl=moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
      }
```

Comment: This is only half the solution. The definition of the `select` callback is incorrect. The correct definition is listed [in the documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/select-callback)